# Como obtener el valor de un Href a traves de Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia. Quiero obtener el valor de un href dentro de una etiqueta "a" con jquery pero al hacer el clic me dice "UNDEFINIED" y no entiendo por que, si mando el id sin el jquery me lo imprime a traves de la url pero con jquery me sale un indefinido...podrian ayudarme?

Codigo del enlace que quiero obtener su HREF

```
 <td><a class=" eliminar btn btn-danger " href="<?php echo $res['idSubsidio']?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
```

Codigo del Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".eliminar").click(function(event) {
      var href = $('this').attr('href');
      alert(href);
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El *this* de `$(this)` es sin comillas, no se trata de un **String**. Con quitarlas ya deberías de conseguir lo que querías con tu función.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".eliminar").click(function(event) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(href);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="eliminar btn btn-danger " href="www.google.es">Enlace</a>
```

Comment: Efectivamente ahi era el error... gracias